# Local: Message timed out error when using AWS MSK Cluster and Confluent.Kafka nuget Package

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I have AWS MSK cluster with 2 broker nodes.
I am not able at all to produce any messages to the brokers always got Local: Message timed out error .

I can access the cluster normally in using AWS CLI
the cluster node doesn't have any authentication just the application should run in a certain AWS VPC

I have tried the simplest example and just replace the bootstrap servers with the AWS Cluster nodes
here is the code

```
string brokerList = "b-1.8.c2.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-2.8.c.c2.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:9092"; // sample nodes examples
```

string topicName = "TestTopic";

```
    var config = new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = brokerList };

    using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, string>(config).Build())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine($"Producer {producer.Name} producing on topic {topicName}.");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");

        try
        {
            var deliveryReport = await producer.ProduceAsync(
                topicName, new Message<string, string> { Key = "MyKey", Value = "MyValue" });

            Console.WriteLine($"delivered to: {deliveryReport.TopicPartitionOffset}");
        }
        catch (ProduceException<string, string> e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"failed to deliver message: {e.Message} [{e.Error.Code}]");
        }
```

I have tried both of TLS and Plaintext which are both allowed in the cluster and got the same error message.

Also have change the cluster configuration from auto.create.topics.enable=false to auto.create.topics.enable=true and still the same result.

i am using the below configuration  setup

Confluent.Kafka nuget version. - Confluent.Kafka 1.4.3
Apache Kafka version. - 2.4.1

Error Message:  Local: Message timed out

Comment: Have you configured the security group to allow traffic to port 9092?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.